# Sending multiple objects in axios.post - firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

I'm trying to send multiple objects with axios.post like that:

```
  export const onOrderSent = (deliveryData,orderData,fullPrice) => {
    return dispatch => {
        let data = {deliveryData,orderData,fullPrice};
        dispatch(sendOrderStart());
        axios.post('/orders.json', data)
            .then(response => {
                ...
            })
            .catch(error => {
                ...
            });
    }
}
```

But it seems to work only if one of them is empty, never two at the same time. If they both have some values, the dispatch is not being sent. btw, fullPrice is a straight value, not an object.
Why is that, and how should I properly send axios.posts with multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending multiple objects in an Array.

```
const data = {objects: [deliveryData, orderData, fullPrice]};
```

Comment: The only change is, that now its all moved into "objects" in data tree, but still not being sent while both objects have some values :(

Comment: Do you see what arrives in the backend or can you share your code for the route?

Comment: if i understand your question good, i only have access to view like that https://imgur.com/a/CvGaZrM

Comment: And, as you see, they both lack orderData :(

Comment: Then it's not an error of the POST Request but how the function "onOrderSend" is called.  Not all parameters are passed then. The error is outside the function. So you would need to post where and how it is called.

Comment: I have finally fixed it, ill post a code as comment

Answer (score 0):

Make it a list of objects like this, i would assume your api would accept a list of object but not a object of objects.

```
        let data = {[deliveryData,orderData,fullPrice]};
```

If this doesn't work look into the backend and see what type of data they're accepting.
i'm pretty sure you should be sending an array of objects, if not, look in the backend.

Comment: Your code gives me Parsing error: unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. That was the stupidest thing, i have ever came across ever, and would never expect it was the problem...
Just add event.preventDefault(); to your handler. Really, working like a charm

```
 orderSendHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        ...
        ///im mapping local state to object here, and then
        const data = {
            deliveryData: formData,
            order: this.props.orderedItems,
            price: this.props.fullPrice
        };
        this.props.onOrderSent(data);
    }
```

and in my actions file, where i operate everything connected to database

```
export const onOrderSent = (data) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(sendOrderStart());
        console.log(data);
        axios.post('/orders.json', data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                dispatch(sendOrderSuccess());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                dispatch(sendOrderFail(error));
            });
    }
}
```